# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'validate' but jquery is loaded

Tags: jquery, validation

I do not understand why I am getting this error.

**Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'validate'**

The jquery is loaded properly, and the validation js also. So why this error? I looked in google and here but they state that it isn't load properly, but in this case it is?

Here I start and the second line gets the error

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#otayhteytta").validate({
        rules: {
            name: "required",
            phone: "required",
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        },
```

Please help and thanks!

Comment: You could at least say where in your code your getting the error? No one's going to trawl through your entire page!

Comment: oh sorry! I forgot, its the line where I start the validation  `$("#otayhteytta").validate({`

Comment: Now that you've solved it, but edited out the link, the question and answer don't make particular sense.  Please consider copying in area in error (too many copies of jquery) into your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are loading two versions of jquery, one from local (1.8.0) and one from google CDN (1.9.1)

Just use one and load it before validate.js script

So you could remove this form your html file:

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for but failed to spot :p

Comment: Thank you! The problem is I have not made this project entirely, but should now correct the form and all this is a little mess. I removed the jquery from the form.html but now I receive two errors: `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.validate.js:1110
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined `

Comment: You have to load jquery BEFORE validate.js

Comment: yes ah thank you so much you are right. I hate this kind of cluttered projects. The problem is the second jquery is loaded at the footer in some strange file, have to go hunting...